# slick: compare LocalDateTime and LocalDate in Rep

Tags: scala, slick, localdate

I want to compare LocalDateTime and LocalDate in sql-filter.

```
overtimed <- tasks if overtimed.deadline <= overtimed.finished
```

where deadline is LocalDate and finished is LocalDateTime

Java can compare these types. Postgres can one also. But slick say

```
 Cannot perform option-mapped operation
      with type: (java.time.LocalDateTime, java.time.LocalDate) => R
  for base type: (java.time.LocalDateTime, java.time.LocalDateTime) => Boolean
```